# php unset object from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove an Article object from an array inside a foreach loop but I am getting the error
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Article as array

```
foreach ($articles as $i => $article) {
    foreach ($categorys as $category) {

        if (checkCategory($category,$article)) {
            unset($article[$i]);
        }
    }
    if ($userName != Null) {
        if ($article->getUserName() != $userName) {
            unset($article[$i]);
        }
    }
    if ($keyWords != Null) {
        if (!containsKeyWords($keyWords, $article)) {
            unset($article[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show ho's your object look like. some values?

Comment: You have a simple typo... use `unset($articles[$i])`.

Comment: Where does the categorys array come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unset from `$articles` array(main or parent array).so do like below:-

```
unset($articles[$i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error gives me some clue that your $article may not be an array but an stdClass Object, you can use`var_dump` to check its type.

you can `unset` an object using `unset($article->{$i})` or `unset($article->somekey)`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`$article` is of an Object type and you're trying to access it via array type.

Try `var_dump()` to check it's type & then accordingly use `unset`.

For array type : `unset($article[$i])`
For object type : `unset($article->{$i})` where $i is key